# LaunchScreen is Blank? XCODE 7.0.1

Tags: ios, xcode

Okay, when creating a new project , in previous versions i find a pretty neat default launchscreen with our app name and copyright infos at the bottom but in XCode 7.0.1 the screen is blank. Is it normal?

Comment: yes it is default. it will be blank.

Comment: Thank you it helped me !

Answer (score 2):

Yes, if you want to create a default launch screen you can use the default launch file. In iOS 8 and later, you can create a XIB or storyboard file instead of a static launch image.

You can check this in the next link:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helped me :)